# How can I speed up this view which sums a load of quote line rows?

Tags: sql, view, performance

I am writing a view to show quote totals based on summing the values in a quote line table. I need to restrict the view to only show quotes for customers of a particular 'pricetype'. However when I do this the view slows down a lot.

SQL to sum the prices

```
SELECT dbo.quoteline.qid, SUM((dbo.pricelist.listprice - dbo.quoteline.voff) * dbo.quoteline.quantity) AS total
FROM dbo.quoteline LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.pricelist ON dbo.quoteline.prodcode = dbo.pricelist.prodcode GROUP BY dbo.quoteline.qid
```

SQL once 'pricetype' constraint is added

```
SELECT     dbo.quoteline.qid, SUM((dbo.pricelist.listprice - dbo.quoteline.voff) * dbo.quoteline.quantity) AS total
FROM         dbo.pricelist RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.client RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.quote ON dbo.client.cid = dbo.quote.cid RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.quoteline ON dbo.quote.qid = dbo.quoteline.qid ON dbo.pricelist.prodcode = dbo.quoteline.prodcode
WHERE     (dbo.client.pricetype = 'V')
GROUP BY dbo.quoteline.qid
```

Maybe its late and I am having a moment but any help here would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: need to see your table and index defs ...

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to show these to you? Just post all the table designs in here (sorry first post so just learning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: First, can you put an index on the dbo.client.pricetype column without it interfering with inserts/updates?  Secondly, inner joins are generally faster than outer joins and since your results and where clause depend on the other tables, I suspect you will want to do inner joins anyways unless there are NULL records you need back from your view.  Try this following query to see if it gets you the results you need:

```
SELECT dbo.quoteline.qid, SUM((dbo.pricelist.listprice - dbo.quoteline.voff) * dbo.quoteline.quantity) AS total
FROM dbo.quoteline 
INNER JOIN dbo.pricelist ON dbo.quoteline.prodcode = dbo.pricelist.prodcode 
INNER JOIN dbo.quote ON dbo.quote.qid = dbo.quoteline.qid 
INNER JOIN dbo.client ON dbo.client.cid = dbo.quote.cid 
WHERE     (dbo.client.pricetype = 'V')
GROUP BY dbo.quoteline.qid
```

Comment: Hi nybbler, This query returns the same correct result set but doesn't appear to have sped it up at all. I've put an index on the pricetype field too. Is it something to do with there being multiple joins to get back to the pricetype field from the quoteline table from where we are summing he lines?

Comment: @Rob If the columns in the tables that you are using for your joins aren't indexed, that would definitely affect the query. Namely, `quote.qid`, `quoteline.qid`, `client.cid`, `quote.cid`, `quoteline.prodcode`, `pricelist.prodcode`.  I maintain legacy systems with far more demanding joins than this that work well.  If you're using MSSQlServer, the estimated execution plan may also be able to recommend some areas for improvement for you.

Comment: I have indexes on all pk and fk columns...maybe I'll try estimated execution plan (never heard of that before)

Comment: @Rob: A quick tutorial on how to read an estimated execution plan can be found here: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans  Let me know how it goes

Comment: Ok looks like I've figured it out. Added an index to the prodcode  column in pricelist table. There are 300k rows in there! Thanks for your help on this @nybbler

Comment: I heard that tables with more rows should be placed more to the left if possible. Is that still relevant, particularly to INNER JOINs, with modern engines?

Comment: @AndriyM: It is entirely situational. My personal experience has been that inner joins perform better for the main systems we maintain, but that could be partly due to the dbserver hardware compared to the network hardware for our customers. For more info on how the joins work, you might want to have a look over this: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4785

Answer (score 0):

What does happen if you do it like this :

```
SELECT     dbo.quoteline.qid, SUM((dbo.pricelist.listprice - dbo.quoteline.voff) * dbo.quoteline.quantity) AS total
FROM         dbo.pricelist RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.client ON dbo.client.pricetype = 'V' RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.quote ON dbo.client.cid = dbo.quote.cid RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.quoteline ON dbo.quote.qid = dbo.quoteline.qid AND dbo.pricelist.prodcode = dbo.quoteline.prodcode
GROUP BY dbo.quoteline.qid
```

Comment: @Rob, FranciscoSoto: The second ON in the last join should be an AND

Comment: Thanks for that nybbler. This query is a lot faster but it returns some rows with null values?!

Comment: Oh yeah, I simply noticed that full join on client, didn't notice that syntax error later.

Comment: @Rob: change right outer joins for inner joins, unless you specifically need null rows from other tables.